# Plot of the algebraic variety of the ideal $I=(x^2+y^2-1)$ of the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

So, in the class of commutative algebra that I attend, we have defined the following:

If $k$ is a field and $I$ is an ideal of the polynomial ring $k[x_1, \ldots , x_n]$, we define the set $V(I)$ as

$V(I)= \{P=(a_1, \ldots,a_n) \in k^n \mid f(P)=0 \ \ \  \forall \ f(x_1,...,x_n) \in I \} $

So, if $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $n=2$, I need to plot the set $V(I)$, for $I=(x^2+y^2-1)$ the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2+y^2-1$ of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$.

I know that $f(x,y) \in I \implies \exists \ \ g(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}[x,y] : f(x,y) = g(x,y)(x^2+y^2-1)$, so, if $(a_1,a_2) \in V(I)$, then $g(a_1,a_2)(a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2-1)=0$. If $g(a_1,a_2) \neq 0 $, it's a circle, but i have no clue what happens when $g(a_1,a_2)=0$.

Comment: I think you're missing the $\forall$ in the definition of $V(I)$. $P \in V(I) \iff f(P) = 0$ for all $f \in I$. Given $P \in V(I)$, since $x^2 + y^2 - 1 \in I$, then in particular we must have $a_1^2 + a_2^2 - 1 = 0$. Letting $C$ be the unit circle, this shows that $V(I) \subseteq C$. Now you still have to show the reverse inclusion; for that you can use your observation about what elements of $I$ look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P \in V(I) \iff f(P) = 0$ for all $f \in I$. Given $P = (a_1,a_2) \in V(I)$, since $x^2 + y^2 - 1 \in I$, then in particular we must have $a_1^2 + a_2^2 - 1 =0$. Letting $C$ be the unit circle, this shows that $V(I) \subseteq C$. Now you still have to show the reverse inclusion; for that you can use your observation about what elements of $I$ look like.